# The attribute "run" already in the main file

Tags: python

I'm using this python code on a discord bot
On the my runner:

```
from lib.bot import main

VERSION = "0.0.1"

main.run(VERSION)
```

On the main file:

```
 def run(self, version):
        self.VERSION = version

        with open("./lib/bot/token", "r", encoding="utf-8") as tf:
            self.TOKEN = tf.read()

        print("Running bot...")
        super().run(self.TOKEN, reconnect=True)
```

It give me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\discord-bot-ultimate\launcher.py", line 5, in <module>
    main.run(VERSION)
AttributeError: module 'lib.bot.main' has no attribute 'run'
```

Can someone tell me what i did wrong.

Comment: Your `run` function looks like it's part of a class. Could you post the full contents of main? Or at least show what context `run` is defined in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def run(self, version)` looks like a method in a class (the parameter `self` hints to it). so you should probably create an instance of the class and use it to call `run`.

I can't give you an exact example since I don't know the rest of your code, but it should look something like this:

for example if `main.py` looks like this:

```py
class Main:
    def run(self, version):
        ... rest of your code ...
```

The class's name in this example is `Main` so we should create an instance of `Main`

so inside `my_runner.py` (or whatever you call your bot script):

```py
from lib.bot import main

VERSION = "0.0.1"

m = main.Main()

m.run(VERSION)
```